# Angular and JWT

Tags: angularjs, jwt

I've been using JSON Web Tokens for sometime now with Angular by passing the token in the header of each request.  This works great for all my applications using this.

My question is, does it HAVE to be passed in the header?  I know that it's probably more secure this way but if the request is made over https, then would it suffice to set it as a GET or POST parameter?

Comment: You can send it to the server however you like (headers, cookies, query string, post body, carrier pigeon). I'm curious what's wrong w/using the header? Out of the options, it seems like the most elegant/safest.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't have to be in the header, but doing so allows you to easily preserve your request types without compromising security.

If you do want to make a GET request, don't pass the JWT in the URL, as that can be intercepted more easily just by monitoring traffic (without actually seeing the request).  You could make the GET request into a POST request and put the JWT into the payload, but that would defeat the purpose of different request types, which would veer away from best practices.

If all you want to do is secure POST and PUT requests, and all of your GET requests are open, then you can send your JWT in the payload.  It might perplex anyone who came across your code later (including you), but there is no technical reason stopping you, and security is the same.

Comment: I'm in agreement with all of this.  But I've seen lately a few people on the interwebs mentioning headers weren't necessary to transfer tokens but they never really explained why so I thought I'd ask and see if anyone has found a case to pass the token via a get or post property.

Comment: GET requests don't have a payload, so your only options consistent across all request types are (i) header or (ii) request URL.  The request URL can be seen by intermediaries even on HTTPS, so that leaves you with just the header option across all request types.